# Speeding up a Pandas apply on a batch of Groups

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe of ~ 1 million rows. They are grouped by a column 'Keyword' with an additional column 'X' and 'Y'.

```
X   Keyword      Y
yy   apply      yy
xx   apply      yy
xy   apply      yx
xx   terms      ix
yy   terms      xi
```

I want to perform some functions on those keywords but I have an awkaward situation. Basically for each group of keywords I want to perform the following:

If greater than one row in size:

- Remove the row where column 'x' is equal to column 'y'
- Keep the rest of the rows

However, in the case of a group with one row where the only row is where 'x' == 'y' then ignore it.

What I have at the moment is:

```
df = df.merge(another_df, on='Keyword', how="inner")
df = df.groupby('Keyword').apply(group_filter)

def group_filter(group):

    if len(group) > 1:

        group = group.query('x != y')

    return group
```

This process is a bit slow and I was wondering if there was any faster way of accomplishing this?

Comment: As you have 1 million rows ,why not store it in a database?

Comment: I suppose I could though I have never done it before, what SQL commands would need to be ran to accomplish what I want? I have a Postgrs database I could use.

Comment: Yes,you could use postgres. For grouping by ,use SQL.To apply the functions use pandas

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, `apply` isn't very speedy.  But IIUC, you can vectorize the operation:

```
group_size = df.groupby("Keyword")["Keyword"].transform("count")
x_eq_y = df["X"] == df["Y"]
df_out = df.loc[(group_size == 1) | (~x_eq_y)]
```

which gives me

```
In [76]: df
Out[76]: 
    X Keyword   Y
0  yy   apply  yy
1  xx   apply  yy
2  xy   apply  yx
3  xx   terms  ix
4  yy   terms  xi
5  ab  unique  ab

In [77]: group_size = df.groupby("Keyword")["Keyword"].transform("count")

In [78]: x_eq_y = df["X"] == df["Y"]

In [79]: df.loc[(group_size == 1) | (~x_eq_y)]
Out[79]: 
    X Keyword   Y
1  xx   apply  yy
2  xy   apply  yx
3  xx   terms  ix
4  yy   terms  xi
5  ab  unique  ab
```